# ASP.NET 4.6, Web address gets appended in address bar rather than being rewritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, visual-studio-2017, navigationbar

I'm creating a new website; however, this is the first time I've run into this problem.  When navigating forward, I can get to the pages I want just fine, but I cannot navigate back unless I use the back button.  If I click a navigation link, I get an HTTP 404 error:

[image]

This appears to happen only when I navigate to another folder in my solution and try to navigate out of it.  I've tried to use the proper amount ../ in front of anchor links to get back. I've tried using the ~/ and ~/ with the proper amount of ../ to navigate.  Neither of those work.  However, It appears if the pages are in the same folder, navigation works fine.  It seems as though this is happening only when I navigate between folders.

The website is not published yet, so I'm only working with IIS Express using Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge to debug.

Please help me figure this issue out.

Comment: use `/path/to/page` which is relative to site root. `~/` should resolve path to the root but sometimes fails. `../../` is the worst way. Without slash (`default.aspx`) the address is relative to *referrer URL*

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It did help me find the problem.  So one of the problems I was having was that the ~ did not work. Each time I used it, it would append the page I wanted to go to to the end of the current address in the bar like this:  http://localhost:xxx/Divisions/~/Default    so I could never go back.  These pages are in the same directory which really threw me.  The fix was that I needed to use just the / without the ~ to grab the page I wanted.  Working perfectly now.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look this up in one of my textbooks from college, but here are three ways to code a path that's relative to the root directory:

1. Start with a forward slash

   href="/Styles/Order.css" rel="stylesheet"
2. Use a tilde (~) operator with server controls

   asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="**~**/Images/banner.jpg"
3. Use the tilde operator and the ResolveURL method with HTML elements

   img src='**<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/banner.jpg")%>**' alt="Image description"

*Reference: Murach's ASP.NET 4.6 Web Programming with C# 2015 6th Edition*

I hope this helps others in the future.